# Выборка из двух таблиц с одинаковыми именами через PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Дорогие друзья. Делаю так :

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product.name as pname ,product.description as pdescr
,с_product.name as сpname,с_product.description as сpdescr FROM product 
,с_product  WHERE product.pid = '$id' ; ")   or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Но в странице правильно выбирается товар только из первой таблицы т е из таблицы `product` а из таблицы `с_product` выбирается первый добавленный товар. Как правильно поставить условие `WHERE`чтоб выбирал правильный товар из обоих таблиц.

Comment: id у товаров в обоих таблицах совпадают? то есть один и тот же товар в разных таблицах будет иметь один и тот же id ?

Comment: Broouzer King, да ID у товаров одинаковый

Comment: *из таблицы с_product выбирается первый добавленный товар* Не верю. Должны выбираться ВСЕ. Или Вы берёте из результирующего набора только первую запись. PS. Добавьте в условие отбора `AND c_product.pid = '$id'`

Comment: Akina, так и происходит поверьте. И пробовал добавить AND c_product.pid = '$id' но потом ничего не выводится (

Comment: Я удивлён что из второй таблицы вообще что-то выбирается. Я бы переписал так: ""SELECT product.name as pname ,product.description as pdescr
,с_product.name as сpname,с_product.description as сpdescr FROM product LEFT JOIN c_product USING(pid) WHERE product.pid = '$id'"

Comment: *пробовал добавить AND c_product.pid = '$id' но потом ничего не выводится* Значит, во второй таблице нет записи с этим id.

Comment: Akina, вот именно что там есть схожие записи) в чем я тоже удивляюсь...

Comment: Устьяннцев Борис, спасибо Вам огромное Ваш ответ мне помог. Сделайте пожалуйста как ответ я бы принял) Akina,  Broouzer King Вам так же спасибо , дорогие друзья!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product.name as pname ,product.description as pdescr ,с_product.name as сpname,с_product.description as сpdescr FROM product LEFT JOIN c_product USING(pid) WHERE product.pid = '$id'" ) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```